# Filtering a select element based on another not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JS like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#DDL1").change(function () {
        var thisValue = $(this).val();

        var $optGroups = $("#DDL2 optgroup");
        $optGroups.hide();

        switch (thisValue) {
            case "11":
                alert(thisValue);
                $optGroups.filter("[label='label1']").show();
                break;
        }

    });
});
```

Basically, based on the selection of the 1st ddl.. I want to filter the 2nd one..

When I run this, `thisValue` = 11, which is what I want.  But `$optGroups` is still showing **all** of the selectable values.. whereas I only want the values that are under the optgroup with a label of `label1` to be shown.

Any explanation on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: If your `DDL1` is a `select` element, then the reason is probably that `optgroup` and `option` elements are treated in a special way by browsers, and it might not be possible to `show`/`hide` them via CSS (what jQuery does). I think the solution is to temporarly `remove` the `optgroup`s which you don't want to show.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási okay is there a way to remove all other labels besides the one I want to show without having to explicitly name all of the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DDL1 is a `select` element, then the reason is probably that `optgroup` and `option` elements are treated in a special way by browsers, and it might not be possible to `show`/`hide` them via CSS (what jQuery does).

Try to dynamically insert the matching `optgroup`s with something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // grab out the initial optgroups from the select and keep them in memory
    var $optGroups = $("#DDL2 optgroup").detach();

    $("#DDL1").change(function () {
        var thisValue = $(this).val();

        // remove all the current optgroups from the select
        $("#DDL2 optgroup").detach();

        switch (thisValue) {
            case "11":
                alert(thisValue);
                // append the matching optgroups to the select
                $optGroups.filter("[label='label1']").appendTo($("#DDL2"));
                break;
        }

    });
});
```

Please note that the code is only for example purposes, not tested in any ways.

Comment: ahh this worked. can you explain why you used `detach` twice?

Comment: First I get the initial optgroups, so I have all of them in memory. And at each change, I have to empty the select, because it can have the previously inserted `optgroup`s. I could have used `empty` or `remove`, but I'm just not sure momentarily about any possible side effect of them (for example `remove` might kill some event handlers or DOM data attached to them, etc.). `detach` is the safest way IMO if you want to just move out the elements from their parent.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any documentation on why some browsers don't use show and hide on select elements?